# Невозможно сохранить значение в файле Excel из Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, openpyxl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Требуется взять значения из одного файла Excel, преобразовать, а затем записать в другой файл Excel Получилось получить значения из исходного файла, преобразовать их, но сохранить значения в файл не удается, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сохранить полученные значения в файл после использования, файл в котором нужно сохранить данные становится битым

```
import openpyxl as op

def FuncAlex(CodeNum: str):
    if CodeNum[0] == '"':
        return (CodeNum[1:-1][0:15])
    else:
        return CodeNum[0:21]


file = 'File1.xlsx'


wb = op.load_workbook(file, read_only= True)
sheet = wb.active
max_row = sheet.max_row
#print(max_row)
res = []

for i in range(1, max_row):
    temp = str(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1).value)
    res.append(FuncAlex(temp))
print(res)

file_res = open("file2.xlsx", "w")
file_res.write(str(res))
file_res.close()
```

Comment: При открытии файлов лучше использовать структуру with. Так вы всегда закроете файл и освободите место для другого дескриптора

Comment: P.S. Возможно, из-за того, что файл как раз и не закрыт, у вас не получается сохранить другой. Это снова к работе with

Comment: Что значит битый файл? Создайте, пожалуйста, минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: вот бы кто придумал читать ошибки... может быть, там что-то полезное...

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну, программист, читающий сообщения об ошибках — неспортивно. Так вы еще от водителей знания ПДД потребуете :)

Comment: Исправление: для тех, кто считает, что я не придумал читать ошибки, то ошибки нет, он просто не записывает в файл @Эникейщик
добавил в описание скрин с ошибкой файла

Comment: Да я пробовал через with, но в файл все равно не записывается @DarkSpace

Comment: @СергейКох я содам пустой файл, в который хочу записать полученные значения, после запуска кода, файл "ломается"

Comment: в вопросе написано "но при сохранении выдает ошибки", в комментарии пишешь "ошибки нет" и тут же пишешь, что добавил скрин с ошибкой.

Comment: @Эникейщик прошу прощения, написал неверно, но я бы хотел не развивать эту телегу дальше, а просто узнать у тех, у кого есть опыт работой с Python+Excel как лучше сохранить полученные значения в файл xlsx

Answer (score 2):

Ну вам же прямым текстом подсказали - "Читаем документацию"!!!

1. Почему вы читаете файл с помощью openpyxl, а пишете назад с помощью функций open и write  из базового модуля????
2. Почему вы пишете в текстовый файл (open по умолчанию пишет в режиме text mode??).
3. Понятно, что несчастный EXCEL увидев файл xlsx и с радостью залезая туда, с огромным удивлением обнаруживает там не xlsx, а текстовый файл, о чем с отвращением вам сообщает.

Не буду за вас делать ваше домашнее задание. Просто покажу, как пишут в xlsx файл с помощью библиотеки openpyxl. А уж под свою задачу тюнингуйте этот скрипт самостоятельно:

```
import openpyxl as op
wb = op.Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active
c1 = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1)
c1.value = "Прежде чем задать вопрос"  
c2 = sheet.cell(row= 1 , column = 2)
c2.value = "Читаем, черт побери, документацию!!!!!!"  
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 25
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 40
wb.save("file2.xlsx")
```

И файл с большим удовольствием открывается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо)
Но удивляет, что все очень грубо воспринимают трудности других людей, это не является моим домашним заданием или еще чем то, а лишь личный интерес)

Comment: вы действительно думаете, что я не пробовал разобраться самостоятельно со своей проблемой, решил впервые воспользоваться форумом, если вы считаете кого то ленивым просто потому что человек задает вопрос, жаль

Comment: @Jacob_Beam Зато это делает вас стрессоустойчивым ;)

Comment: Возможно @DarkSpace )))